# Do I have any alternatives to matching on a hash or using a cursor?

Tags: sql, cursor

Still new to sql development, but learning a lot fast.

This scenario would be solved with entity framework, but that is not an option.

Need to insert data into two tables. Below describes the situation.

The Main table has an identity key and the sub table needs that key as well when data related to the records tied to the key get inserted.

The source info is coming from a few other tables. I can't make changes to the Main or Sub table structure.

I am trying to avoid using a cursor, but I don't see any alternatives.

I tried using output inserted.main_id into #temp1  - which works, but I can't find a way to put the Sub_ID into that temp table as well. The Sub_ID is coming from the source.

They way I have it working is inserting the data into the Main table then by matching up a hash in the source against the Main table I can then insert the Main_ID into the Sub table with the corresponding Sub_ID.

Example

```
TABLE MAIN    
Main_ID    PK, bigint,not null - identity
FirstName    varchar(15) not null
LastName    varchar(15) not null
Misc1    varchar(15)null
Misc2    varchar(15) null
Misc3    varchar(15) null

TABLE SUB    
Main_ID    PK,FK,bigint, not null
Sub_ID    int null
Misc4    varchar(15)
Misc5    varchar(15)
Misc6    varchar(15)
```

Is there a way to capture the Sub_ID along with "output inserted.main_id" into a temp table?

Right now what I am doing is matching a hash from the source and the records inserted into the Main table to get the Main_ID that will be inserted into the Sub table.

If I could capture the Sub_ID into a temp table when the Main_ID is generated in the Main table the process would be a lot faster. I wanted to avoid using a cursor, but I think that is my best option right now.